# Find highest value in Get-ADOrganizationalUnit Name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am currently using:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=Students 20*)' -SearchBase 'OU=Students,OU=VAL Accounts,DC=VAL,DC=VAL,DC=VAL,DC=au' | ft Name
```

Which generates the following:

> Students 2009
> Students 2010
> Students 2011
> Students 2012
> Students 2013
> Students 2014
> Students 2015
> Students 2016
> Students 2017
> Students 2018
> Students 2019

I wish to get the highest year and save it as a value to use later in the program.

I.E: `$value = 'Students 2019'`

As 2019 is the highest number in the list

Comment: please, DO NOT use any of the `Format-*` cmdlets if you want to use the output for anything other than _final_ output to the screen or a plain text file. why? those cmdlets butcher your objects & output the remnants wrapped in formatting code.

Comment: How would you suggest doing it?

Comment: use the `Select-Object` cmdlet ... that is what it is designed for. [*grin*]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a property to the objects to represent the year.  Something like:

```
$OUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=Students 20*)' -SearchBase 'OU=Students,OU=VAL Accounts,DC=VAL,DC=VAL,DC=VAL,DC=au' | 
Select-Object *,@{Name = 'OU_Year'; Expression = { $_.Name.Split(' ')[1] }} 

$LatestYear = ($OUs | Sort-Object OU_Year | Select-Object -Last 1).OU_Year
```

$LatestYear should be 2019.

Answer (score 1):

here's a slightly different way to get the highest year number ADO. [*grin*]

what it does ...

[1] the first 16 lines create a collection of objects to sort
you would pro'ly use something like ...

```
$GADOU_Params = @{
    LDAPFilter = '(name=Students 20*)'
    SearchBase = 'OU=Students,OU=VAL Accounts,DC=VAL,DC=VAL,DC=VAL,DC=au'
    }
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit @GADOU_Params |
    Select-Object -Property Name
```

[2] sorts the list by a calculated property
it takes the `.Name` prop, splits on the space, and then uses the last part of that split.

[3] takes the last of the items from the above sort

[4] displays the resulting item
if you want ONLY the name [instead of the prop that holds that value], add a `.Name` to the end of line 19 [the `Sort-Object` line].

here's the code ...

```
# fake reading in a list of objects
#    in real life, use something like Import-CSV or Get-ADOrganizationalUnit
$ADO_List = @'
Name
Students 2009
Students 2010
Students 2011
Students 2012
Students 2013
Students 2014
Students 2015
Students 2016
Students 2017
Students 2018
Students 2019
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$HighestYearADO = ($ADO_List |
    Sort-Object {$_.Name.Split(' ')[-1]})[-1]

$HighestYearADO
```

output ...

```
Name         
----         
Students 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

Did I misread the original question? I thought you just wanted the year, but if you want the name value from the latest OU I don't think you need to do any of the Select-Object stuff.

Maybe something like:

```
$OUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=Students 20*)' -SearchBase 'OU=Students,OU=VAL Accounts,DC=VAL,DC=VAL,DC=VAL,DC=au'
$NewestOUName = ($OUs | sort-object Name)[-1].Name
```

You could make this in to a one-liner, but it might not be worth it.